# On Overcoming the Conflict Between Lmodern and Bold Smallcaps When Compiling with Pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, fontspec, font-encodings, small-caps, lmodern

I am working on a document which invokes both `fontenc` and `lmodern`, and ran into a problem with producing bold smallcaps.

I came across this post: [How te get bold + small caps with latin modern or computer modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334368/how-te-get-bold-small-caps-with-latin-modern-or-computer-modern) which offers a (Xelatex) solution with the `fontspec` package---but as I am invoking `fontenc` (and am compiling with `pdflatex`)---an adaptation of that solution to my situation would be out.

Nevertheless, after looking at the OP's MWE, I have obtained the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,lettrine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Needed to make the letters folloiwng the lettrine boldface.
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
   \rmfamily
   %\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{b}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}
   \DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.25]{\initfamily{T}}{\textbf{he}} 
\end{document}
```

which seems to work (though I have some questions):

[image]

*Note:* The OP makes use of both of commands: `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{b}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}` and `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}`; though I have found that `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}` alone works for me. (The only difference I see between the two is {b} vs. {bx}).

QUESTION: Can anyone tell me (when compiling with `Pdflatex`), the difference between the two; if both are needed for the purpose of obtaining bold smallcaps when `\lmodern` is invoked; and if, perhaps, there is a better way of accomplishing this than this approach which does seem to work without using `fontspec`, as I am precluded from so doing by the use of `fontenc` and `pdflatex`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `b` and `bx` forms of the command set what happens when you use `\fontseries{b}` and `\fontseries{bx}`, respectively. They stand for Bold and Bold Extended. (If a font has a bold condensed series, that is `bc`, and so on.) Neither Computer Modern nor Latin Modern has a non-extended bold face, so the LaTeX commands `\textbf` and `\bfseries` select `bx`.

Since some font packages use `b` and some use `bx`, it’s good practice to define both.  This lets you change the font family without losing your bold formatting, whatever other fonts you might be using.  In your own document, though, you control what formatting commands you use, and you can skip the `b` alias if you want.

Comment: Thank you for providing this explanation. Would you say this approach to correcting the `lmodern` smallcaps problem is OK then? I couldn't find what seemed like a "canonical" method, so I figured I would give this a try.

Comment: @mlchristians You mentioned you cannot use modern fonts as a solution. You might use the default `cmr` instead of `lmodern` if you need its features, or you might [use commands such as here to format your lettrines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359303/lettrine-temporary-font-change), if that is where you need them.

Comment: Thank you kindly.